# Questions abaout ring

Tags: ring-theory

I have a comutative ring (R,+,.) with unity then i have to say which of the following is true:

A[X]=A[[X]]
A[X] included in A
A[X] included in A[[X]]
A[[X]] included in A[X]

I can't figure it out.

Comment: Recall the definitions of polynomial and power series rings to rule out the first and last choices (because any power series with an infinite number of terms is NOT a polynomial).  On the other hand, a polynomial is a power series which just happens to have only finitely many non-zero terms, so the third choice is true. The second choice is obviously false, since the indeterminate "$x$" is not in $A$.

Comment: Hi Darius, welcome to SE. Please be more specific than simply "I can't figure it out". Show us what you've tried, and where you got stuck. The fact that "you can't figure it out" is obvious, since you'd not have posted the question if you *could* figure it out. Also, @Nick, consider posting an answer as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Nick thank you, i understand it now, my notes wasn't so clear about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what each of these are?

$$A[x]=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\mid a_i\in A\right\}$$

$$A[[x]]=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ix^i\mid a_i\in A\right\}$$

Clearly each element of $A$ is an element of both of these because we can choose the polynomial $a_0+0x+0x^2+\dots$.

Note the only difference in the first and second definition is that in the first, we must have all terms zero after some point. In the second, we can have nonzero terms forever. So which one should be a subset of the other?

Comment: Thank you for the explication, i didn't find the second definition in my theory notes but now i understand.